# Call method onSubmit of another button

Tags: wicket

I have 1 ajax button and 1 link:

```
AjaxButton buttonA = new AjaxButton("buttonA") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        info("buttonA");
    }
}

Link<void> buttonB = new Link<void>("buttonB") {
    ...
}
```

I want to when I click buttonB is equivalent to buttonA click

Please help me.

Comment: "I want to when I cluck buttonB then execute button.onSubmit()" doesnt make any sense.  Please rephrase the question

Answer (score 1):

Extract the body of ButtonA#onSubmit() to a separate method and just call this method in ButtonB#onClick()

```
private void doWork() {...}

AjaxButton buttonA = new AjaxButton("buttonA") {

   @Override
   protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     doWork();
   }
}

Link<void> buttonB = new Link<void>("buttonB") {
   @Override public void onClick() {
     doWork();
   }
}
```